# How to access elements from 3 lists with index set at minimum value from one list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, numpy

Say I have 3 lists of the same dimensions which contains elements of velocity, distance and time.

```
    V = [1, 2, 3, 4, -5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
    D = [10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2]
    T = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

If I want to find the minimum velocity in my V list I can just do

```
    np.amin(V)
```

and I will get 5 in this case. But then how do I go about printing/getting/returning my value of D and T at that specific V? I have tried something like this

```
    def MAXVTIME(VELOCITY, DISTANCE, TIME):
        for i, (VELOCITY, DISTANCE, TIME) in enumerate(zip(VELOCITY, DISTANCE, TIME)):
            if VELOCITY == np.amin(VELOCITY):
                return VELOCITY.i(np.amin(VELOCITY))
```

but I can't get it to work. I need my function to be able to input 3 lists of velocity, distance and time, choose the smallest velocity value, and return the velocity, distance and time at that value.

Think of this as a person falling down, its smallest speed will be its maximum velocity(taking downwards as negative), and the distance is decreasing while time is ticking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.argmin`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmin.html), which returns the first index of the minimum value.

```
import numpy as np

V = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, -5, 4, 3, 2, 1])
D = np.array([10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2])
T = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])

i = np.argmin(V)

V_min = V[i]  # -5
D_min = D[i]  # 6
T_min = T[i]  # 5
```

Comment: Lovely. Exactly what I wanted. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try without numpy in one line if you want:

```
print(min([i for i in enumerate(zip(V,D,T))],key=lambda x:x[1][0]))
```

output:

```
(4, (-5, 6, 5))
```